# Change string in iOS with respect to System language

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nslocalizedstring, nslocale

I would like to display date in below format Jan 23, week 2, 2015. 
On Change of Language settings week string is remain in english others changed system language, So i have implemented Localization for the word "week" using localizable.string file and all changed done and it is working fine. My question is, IS there a way to get system language and convert string for this language without localization procedures? Since for this single word i need to add more localizable.strings!

Comment: so you're looking for help with NSDateFormatter and/or NSLocale ?

Comment: yes, nsdateformatter type automatically converting string (from date) to current language . Need to append word "week" along with this with local language.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you want custom wording you have to handle them in the Localizable.strings file for all languages you want to support.

You can have several syntax for the dates using DD, MM, YYYY, EEEE, ... (You have them all for iOS 7+ [UNICODE LOCALE DATA MARKUP LANGUAGE](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)) but yours is not listed.

Hope it helps.

Tom

Comment: I have completed everything! just want to know is there a easy way to convert a simple nsstring for given locale except from using localzable.string